# Upload image using Python - can't get it to work

Tags: php, python, post, upload, python-requests

I'm struggling to find the error in my code here
I've got the following html form:

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
Select image to upload:
<input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
<input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>
```

And the following python code:

```
files={'fileToUpload': open('uploading.jpg', 'rb')}
p=requests.post(url, files=files)
```

p.text just returns the full html of the page, nothing

Comment: I forgot that `requests` does a lot of auto-magic -.- Sorry for any confusion. What's in your `upload.php`? Does a manual upload work?

Comment: Add this to your post request: `data={'submit':'Upload Image'}`

Comment: My upload.php is a direct copy of https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

Comment: Adding the data value doesn't seem to change anything

Comment: A manual upload works fine